# Are there any tools for compile time checking of asserts in c++?

Tags: c++, assert

I was writing a function in c++ the other day and it occured to me the compiler could do a lot more to help me guard against mistakes. The essentials of my code were like this -

```
void method(SomeType* p)
{
    assert(p != 0);
    p->something();
}
```

And it was called like this

```
SomeType p = NULL;
if (SomeCondition)
{
    p = some_real_value;
}

method(p);
```

Clearly it's possible for p to be null at run time and therefore the assertion on the method to fail in a debug build. My mistake.

However it seems possible that that the compiler could have caught this at compile time and issued a warning saying that it has detected it has found a possibility that the assertion could be violated.

Ok this is a simple case and it would be fairly simple for the compiler to spot that the pointer could be NULL at that point based on some flow analysis of the program and tracking of possible ranges of variables at each point.

I know that it would likely be too difficult to determine if many asserts would be violated but if even a small number times the compiler was able to tell me that I've written code where it's possible that an assertion is violated it would help make my programs that much safer.

I'm thinking that it would help with things like off by one errors in array indexing too for example inside a loop :-

```
assert(index >= 0 && index < array_size);
```

I'm thinking that in many cases the compiler could prove at compile that the index variable could possibly be outside of those bounds and issue a warning at compile time.

I realise that this is likely to be far too much work for a complier to do normally but perhaps there are some tools that can perform this kind of analysis? I've not been able to find anything with google but I was wondering if anything of this kind exists? Or is it just too hard to do well enough to be useful perhaps?

Comment: There's no way for compiler to know the value of the variables in compile time. It's known only in runtime.

Comment: Most static code analysis tools do most of what you describe. They do produce a large number of false positives but they are easy to spot/filter out. Are you looking for something else?

Comment: The availability of tools depend on factors like OS, licensing fees etc. If you are on Linux, Valgrind is a good thing to try. VS Team System comes with its own code analysis (turn it on using `/analyze` compiler option).

Comment: @Drakosha Of course there is, if you have a standard for loop counting from 0 to 49 then the compiler can infer that the loop variable only can contain that range. If it's passed to a method that does an assert(i < 40) then the compiler can flag something might be wrong... I'll accept that it's not trivial to do though and impossible in many cases

Comment: @JB: yes, but those cases are very limited. Besides anyone can take an address of a variable, cast it to whatever and change it and the compiler will never know it happened.

Comment: @Drakosha  the *important* cases may be very limited as well - e.g. to inner loops where the program spends 90+% of its time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Static analysis tools such as PC-lint may be able to detect these issues.
http://www.gimpel.com/html/pcl.htm

With respect to your first example though: my style is to favour references over pointer arguments or return values unless NULL is an acceptable value.  This eliminates the need to assert arguments are != NULL.

Comment: +1 re both Gimpel Lint being a good tool for this and your preferred style removing the need.

Comment: I agree, although that was just intended as a simple example

Comment: Ah static analysis was the search keyword I was missing. I tried everything else I could think of

Comment: Accepted this answer, it's hard though when there are more than one similar answer

Answer (score 3):

The Boost library has a compile-time assert. A very simple example would be:

```
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>
...
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(1 > 0);
```

Boost has a comprehensive set of compile-time tools of every description, although these can only detect possible run-time failures at compile-time if you can express the test as a compile-time invariant.

Comment: Although useful, compile time asserts are something different really

Answer (score 2):

The class of tools that do this sort of checking is called *static analysis*. One such example is [Coverity](http://coverity.com) (a commercial product, and if you have to ask "how much" then you can't afford it). I don't know what sort of open source tools are available for the same purpose (for C++).

For Java, [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) is an excellent static analysis tool (not as comprehensive as Coverity, but you won't have to mortgage your house to use it).